# Chaining a number of callables into a single function

Tags: python

How would you name this function (I gave in a name `pipe` in the example) which constructs combines a chain of functions with a single attribute into a single callable:

```
# Python
def pipe(*functions):
    """
    pipe(c, b, a)(value) == a(b(c(value)))
    """
    if len (functions) == 1:
        return functions[0]
    def chain(val):
        for func in functions:
            val = func(val)
        return val
    chain.func_name = '__'.join(repr(f) for f in functions)
    return chain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function performs [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), so the name should be `compose`. Or rather `reverse_compose`, because it applies functions in the order reversed from natural composition.

Comment: Do you think it would be include to include something like `nary_compose` or `multi_compose`, or is `compose` alone sufficient?

Comment: Unless you plan to add other compositors, I'd stick with plain compose. Otherwise, a distinctive prefix may be necessary.